# Get content of php file in PHP

Tags: php, ftp, ob-get-contents

I'm using ftp_get to get content of a php file from FTP in PHP.

```
ob_start();
$result = ftp_get($ftp_conn, "php://output", "file.php", FTP_BINARY);
$data = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

This is file.php

```
<?php echo "string"; ?>
```

But it show php code, not content of "echo" in that php file. There any do this?

Thank so much!

Comment: Do you want to run the code in the file?

Comment: To execute the contents of a file (`$data` is of type string), use `eval()`.

Comment: Is the file available over an http(s) connection? Then you can use `file_get_contents()` instead of ftp. Otherwise you would need `eval()`.

Comment: You **are** *"getting content of php file"*. If you need something else, you have to tell us.

Comment: @SubashKharel I want get result of php file, in this case is "string" text that file echo.

Comment: eva() not working.

Comment: eval() will not work. eval doesn't like the `<?` and `?>`. You can strip these token out of the result and then do an eval().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very ugly, but may succeed

```
ob_start();
$result = ftp_get($ftp_conn, "localcopy.php", "file.php", FTP_BINARY);
include("localcopy.php");
$data = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
$result = ftp_get($ftp_conn, "php://output", "file.php", FTP_BINARY);
```

With this:

```
require 'file.php';
$data = ob_get_contents();
```

Comment: file.php is not local, it's on a ftp-server

Comment: Then you can use eval() function, but it could be very dangerous

Comment: But best way to get resutl of php file is use it as API.
That means you use curl() function and run the script on server, where is placed.

Comment: Why not do both? download and store the file somewhere and then `require` it? That way you are avoiding eval